# how to include enum key and value inside SelectListItem?

Tags: c#, enums, ienumerable

I try to convert Enum to SelectListItem. I can get the text but I can't get the value itself.

here is my attempt.

```
      // A method to convert Enum to SelectListItem
      public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumSelectList<T>()
      {
          return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(
            enu => new SelectListItem() { Text = enu.ToString(), Value = enu.ToString() })).ToList();
      }
```

this method returns `Text = enu.ToString(), Value = enu.ToString()`

returning Text is fine but it is the same with Value.

I don't know how to retrieve values of the enum so I can get 0,1 instead of Import or Export

Comment: Cast it to an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you didn't change your underlying enum type (default is `int`), you can just cast it:

```
new SelectListItem() { Text = enu.ToString(), Value = (int) enu }
```

If you changed the underlying type (e.g. to `Guid`), of course make sure to cast it to the appropriate type.